# SslStream.WriteAsync "The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending"

Tags: c#, sslstream

How to prevent this issue when writing data to the client Asynchronously

```
The BeginWrite method cannot be called when another write operation is pending
```

MYCODE

```
public async void Send(byte[] buffer)
{
    if (buffer == null)
        return;
    await SslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code? I think that when you get the error your async write operations overlap.

Comment: Are you calling this method from a single thread?

Comment: I think with Async i don't worry about threadings ?!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is important to understand exactly what the await keyword does:

> An await expression does not block the thread on which it is
>   executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the
>   async method as a continuation on the awaited task. Control then
>   returns to the caller of the async method. When the task completes, it
>   invokes its continuation, and execution of the async method resumes
>   where it left off ([MSDN - await (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx)).

When you call Send with some non null buffer you will get to

```
    await SslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Using await you block the execution only in the Send method, but the code in the caller continues to execute even if the WriteAsync has not completed yet. Now if the Send method is called again before the WriteAsync has completed you will get the exception that you have posted since SslStream does not allow multiple write operations and the code that you have posted does not prevent this from happening.

If you want to make sure that the previous BeginWrite has completed you have to change the Send method to return a Task

```
    async Task Send(SslStream sslStream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            return;

        await sslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

and wait for it's completion by calling it using await like:

```
    await Send(sslStream, message);
```

This should work if you do not attempt to write data from multiple threads.

Also here is some code that prevents write operations from multiple threads to overlap (if properly integrated with your code). It uses an intermediary queue and the Asynchronous Programming Model(APM) and works quite fast.
You need to call EnqueueDataForWrite to send the data.

```
    ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> writePendingData = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
    bool sendingData = false;

    void EnqueueDataForWrite(SslStream sslStream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (buffer == null)
            return;

        writePendingData.Enqueue(buffer);

        lock (writePendingData)
        {
            if (sendingData)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                sendingData = true;
            }
        }

        Write(sslStream);            
    }

    void Write(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = null;
        try
        {
            if (writePendingData.Count > 0 && writePendingData.TryDequeue(out buffer))
            {
                sslStream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, WriteCallback, sslStream);
            }
            else
            {
                lock (writePendingData)
                {
                    sendingData = false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception then
            lock (writePendingData)
            {
                sendingData = false;
            }
        }            
    }

    void WriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        SslStream sslStream = (SslStream)ar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            sslStream.EndWrite(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // handle exception                
        }

        Write(sslStream);
    }
```

Comment: Great explanation and examples Andrei, thank-you. Your code for preventing writes from multiple threads works well, I have been attempting to write very similar code :).

Comment: Very nice. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If the operation was started with BeginWrite, call [SslStream.EndWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.endwrite.aspx) to end the old write operation before you start the next. If the operation was started using [WriteAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629.aspx), ensure the Task has completed first, such as using the `await` keyword or [Wait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx).

Comment: i am using it this way but it continue to tell me the same message

Comment: await SslStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

Comment: Is anything else using the stream and not cleaning up or timing out? According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/2a9890c4-4e4f-40ec-9da2-2ff1ca2ce32d/, the SslStream class intentionally prevents multiple simultaneous reads and writes.

Comment: Only the BeginRead, but no other BeginWrites !

Comment: i am also trying MemoryStream's await s.CopyToAsync(SslStream);. But the same error this is driving me crazyy

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine but I think a more concise explanation (which is what I was looking for when I searched for the same error message) is this:

The method isn't thread-safe but is being called in a non-thread safe manner, because you aren't `await`ing your `Send` method.